# How to trace an event trigger in backbone (add triggered for every model in collection)

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have some unexpected behavior in a Backbone view, "add" is being triggered for every model in a collection that was fetched, but I would expect just sync would be. So I know something funny is going on but I'm having trouble detecting what it is as the code touches a lot of files.

Does anyone have any advice how I can debug where/what is triggering the add? Or even what may cause add to be triggered for every model when I'm just fetching the collection?

For example, when I run:

```
@listenTo @collection, 'add', @adding
@listenTo @collection, 'sync', @synching

adding: -> console.log 'adding'
synching: -> console.log 'synching'
```

I get 'render' logged 20 times (number of models in the collection), but 'synching' just once, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular `Backbone.Collection.fetch(...)` uses `Collection.set(...)` to populate the models.  [Here's the line from the source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-118) showing the code.  `Collection.set(...)` fires `add` events for every model returned.

If you're actually fetching the "initial" set of models, you probably want to "reset" the collection when the data is returned:

```
var collection = new MyCollection();
collection.fetch({ reset: true });
```

This will cause the collection to use `reset` when the data is returned, which does not fire `add` events.  [Here's the source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-105) for `reset(...)`; note it uses `this.add(...)` but passes in the `silent` flag.  So you will get a single `reset` event, followed by a single `sync` event.